# Проверка правильности даты как функция член или как отдельная функция?

Tags: c++, функции

В книге Programming Principles And Practice Using C++ в качестве примера рассматривается разработка класса Date. По ходу разбираются методы проверки введенного значения на привильность с помощью функции-члена is_valid():

```
// simple Date (prevent invalid dates)
class Date {
    public:
    class Invalid { };    // to be used as exception
    Date(int y, int m, int d); // check for valid date and initialize
    // . . .
    private:
    int y, m, d; // year, month, day
    bool is_valid();// return true if date is valid
};
/*We put the testing of validity into a separate is_valid() function
 because checking for validity is logically distinct from initialization
 and because we might want to have several constructors. As you can see,
 we can have private functions as well as private data: */
Date::Date(int yy, int mm, int dd)
    : y{yy}, m{mm}, d{dd}
{
    if (!is_valid()) throw Invalid{};
}
bool Date::is_valid()
{
    if (m<1 || 12<m) return false;
    // . . .
}
```

То есть при вызове какого бы то ни было конструктура, функция член is_valid() всегда проверит полученное значение, и в случае чего выкинет исключение, но далее по тексту:

> Note also that we introduced a helper function is_date(). That function **replaces** Date::is_valid() because checking whether a date is valid is largely independent of the representation of a Date. For example, we don’t need to know how Date objects are represented to know that “January 30, 2008” is a valid date and “February 30, 2008” is not. There still may be aspects of a date that depend on the representation (e.g., can we represent “January 30, 1066”?), but (if necessary) Date’s constructor can take care of that.

То есть автор выносит проверку даты в отдельную функцию, так как "проверка корректности даты не зависит от способы представления класса Date". Я никак не могу понять, какую *идею* преследует автор? С проверкой даты вполне справлялась функция-член, год всё-равно внешняя функция не проверит (1066 - выглядит как правильный год). В чём суть такой подмены, и что понимается под "we don’t need to know how Date objects are represented"?

Comment: а как выглядит упомянутая `is_date`?

Comment: под `we don’t need to know how Date objects are represented` подразумевается именно то, что написано - 30 февраля будет невалидной датой, вне зависимости от того, как внутри в классе Date оно будет представлено (в виде отдельных year/month/day, или еще как-то)

Comment: @PashaPash, никак. Автор акцентирует на идее того, что функцию-помощник is_date() можно вынести за пределы класса, так как "checking whether a date is valid is largely independent of the representation of a Date.". Дан лишь пример объявления :    ' bool is_date(int y, Month m, int d); '  // true for valid date'

Comment: @PashaPash, да, но ведь когда используется функция-член is_valid() - 30 февраля по-прежнему будет ошибкой.

Comment: никто не знает что хотел сказать автор. по мне - так выглядит совершенно надуманно. в том числе и потому, что валидность даты на самом деле зависит от представления - от того, в каком календаре заданы day/month/year (да, не все пользуются григорианским календарем :)

Comment: Ну, `is_gregorean_date_valid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне кажется, идея автора состоит в том, что *разделение кода на классы должно соответствовать зависимостям между сущностями*. Эту туманную фразу как раз хорошо продемонстрировать на примере из вашего вопроса.

Проверка того, является ли тройка (день, месяц, год) правильной григорианской датой, не зависит от того, как мы храним дату, и храним ли мы её вообще.

У вас может вовсе не быть необходимости в хранении дат. Или наоборот, вам нужны различные формы хранения: хранение в виде дня, месяца и года (более эффективная работа с датами) или в виде количества миллисекунд от начала Эпохи (более эффективный расход памяти). Вне зависимости от этого проверка будет выглядеть так же. В какой из классов, представляющих дату вы положите проверку?

Если не делать эту функцию частью класса, ею можно будет воспользоваться при любой реализации класса, представляющего дату. Эта функция имеет ценность и без конкретного способа хранения даты — то есть, конкретного класса.

Таким образом, сущность «проверки дня/месяца/года» отделяется от сущности «хранение даты».

---

Принцип, о котором говорит книга, не специфичен для C++. Это скорее общий принцип избавления от ненужной связанности сущностей.

Comment: "Принцип, о котором говорит книга, не специфичен для C++", ну собственно книга  основной упор делает на идеи и способы их выражения, а не на конкретном инструменте (C++). Я еще раз попытался вникнуть в написанное и пришёл к похожему выводу - неважно, как представлена дата в классе, её валидность от этого не зависит, но, если например класс в принципе не может представить дату (Дата представляется в виде кол-ва дней с 01.01.1990) хотя она и валидна (01.01.1567), то "constructor can take care of that" :D

Answer (score 2):

Главная идея объектно-ориентированного программирования - это абстракция, то есть обобщение, когда понятие освобождается от "шелухи" деталей.

Данная функция имеют более обобщенное значение, которое вообще не зависит от того, существует ли данный класс даты или нет, создавали ли вы объекты этого класса или нет.

Эта функция выполняет, как я понимаю, проверку того, что переданные ей в качестве аргументов три значения представляют собой корректную дату.

Чтобы воспользоваться этой функцией, нет необходимости создавать объекты данного класса дата.

То есть абстракция корректная дата - это самостоятельное обобщенное понятие, независящее от конкретной реализации класса дата.

Comment: Согласен, но здесь, вероятно, автор также имел ввиду, что вынесение функций, так или иначе касающихся реализации, облегчит поиск ошибок "When we design our interfaces to be minimal (though complete), we have to leave out lots of operations that are merely useful. <...> That way, a bug in that (outside) function cannot directly corrupt the data in a class object. " К тому же реализация может представлять дату, как количество дней с определенного момента, а не просто (день,мес,год), но валидность всё равно нужно проверить. В общем вот такая муть :).

Comment: @jumpjet67 Класс даты по определению должен предоставлять корректные даты. Это не его функция - проверять правильность произвольно взятой даты, заданной как три целых числа. То есть класс создается не для этого. Он сам может быть клиентом этой функции, когда вызывается его конструктор.

Comment: ну так я и не имел ввиду, что класс сам должен проверять валидность, я написал, что "валидность всё равно нужно проверить", а как это сделать? Автор, как и вы, говорите, что правильнее будет обособить это функцию вне класса - пусть так.

Answer (score 0):

Мы сначала сконструировали дату, а потом вызвали `is_valid` - для данного представления это работает. А теперь предположим, что мы считаем дату в днях от начала 2000 года. Тогда мы переводим её в число и упс - нам больше нечего валидировать - любое число корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что автор подрывает теоретическую основу ООП о том, что данные и их обработка должны быть связанными сущностями. Это и вызывает основное непонимание.

Кроме того, зная устройство того, как хранятся данные, можно написать гораздо более оптимальный и быстрый валидатор, нежели обобщенный сферический валидатор всех дат на свете, неважно как представленных.

Итого, у автора - бардак в голове. Он подрывает идеи ООП прямо во время обучения ООП, он преподает паршивый антипаттерн о решении глобальных задач вместо конкретных.

Вердикт - работу автора признать вредной и отправить в топку.

Comment: Мощно вы на Страуструпа :)

Comment: @VladD Меня мало интересует жирность авторитетов. Недостатки подхода тоже нужно показывать, иначе обучение будет несовсем честным. Да, это красивая теоретическая идея, но на практике - за время, потраченное на написание универсального валидатора, который реально даром никому не нужен, лид руку не пожмет.

Comment: Ну, на мнение техлида мне _всё равно_ ещё больше, чем на мнение Страуструпа. А вот валидатор даты на мой вкус имеет отдельный смысл независимо от формата хранения. // Даже если вы храните дату в тиках, у вас в любом случае должен быть конструктор из y+m+d, правильно? Значит, и проверка нужна всё равно.

Comment: @VlaD я могу получать дату исключительно из базы данных, по протоколу с защитой корректности. И на кой ляд мне тогда дополнительная проверка? Программирование должно быть достаточно конкретным, иначе куча времени уйдет на несуществующие задачи.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, вы исповедуете YAGNI. Мне никогда не нравился принцип YAGNI, доведённый до крайности. Так можно дойти до того, что если в вашей программе из RGB используется только R и G, ты вы не внесёте B в структуру, описывающую цвет.

Comment: А надеяться на «базу данных и протокол» — это с моей точки зрения сильная связность. Мне кажется, компонента должна разрабатываться не зная подробностей архитектуры системы.

Comment: Впрочем, мне кажется, мы уходим куда-то в офтопик и философию.

Comment: @Vlad то, что я пишу здесь может и не совпадать с моим личным мнением. А используя только два байта из структуры, я сэкономлю 50% памяти, так как мне не придется фактически хранить 4 байта на каждую тройку из соображений выравнивания.

Comment: Я же говорю, это уже больше философия и личные предпочтения в программировании.